# gdb - list source of current function without typing its name

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

In GDB, the command:

```
list function
```

will list all the source for the function.

Is there a command that will list all of the source of the function you are currently in, without requiring you to manually type the function name?

Comment: it prints a number of lines but not the whole function.

Comment: You can keep hitting enter after `list function` to repeat the previous command and continue printing out the function 10 lines at a time.

Comment: And you can also run `gdb` inside Emacs with `M-x gdb`; I find this very useful.

Comment: By "implicitly" do you mean without typing the function name directly?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 Yes - since a C program is a collection of functions you are always in a function, that's guaranteed. It would be useful to have a shortcut which will list the current function implicitly (i.e. without specifying the name of the curent function).

Comment: Thanks, so this is the question I wanted. Edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(gdb) help list
List specified function or line.
With no argument, lists ten more lines after or around previous listing.
"list -" lists the ten lines before a previous ten-line listing.
One argument specifies a line, and ten lines are listed around that line.
Two arguments with comma between specify starting and ending lines to list.
Lines can be specified in these ways:
  LINENUM, to list around that line in current file,
  FILE:LINENUM, to list around that line in that file,
  FUNCTION, to list around beginning of that function,
  FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
  *ADDRESS, to list around the line containing that address.
With two args if one is empty it stands for ten lines away from the other arg.
```

The `*ADDRESS` is what is interesting.

On x86/x64 current pointer is in `rip` register so:

```
(gdb) list *$pc
0x7ffff7b018a0 is at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82.
77  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
```

The example is from `cat` command as I don't have anything with debug info at hand.

Comment: This id not work for me on GDB 7.7: it printed `10` lines around the current line, just like `list`, not the entire function.

Comment: Why does `rip` being the program counter make any difference if you use `$pc`, the GDB's generic name for program counter? And, actually, on x86 (32-bit) it's not `rip` – there's even no such register. It's instead `eip`.

Comment: Yeah this does not behave any differently to just `list`.

Answer (score 5):

When you are stopped in a function type ***bt*** for backtrace.
Backtrace will list the current stack. The element at the top, #0, is usually the function you are interested in and the source file and line number is listed also.

For example:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  myClass::EntityTypeStruct::readAttributes (this=0x7fffd00066e0, buf=0x7fffd0006020 "", len=48)
    at /team/project/src/EntityTypeStruct.cc:55
#1  0x000000000044ca86 in workerThread (ts=0x7fffea71dcc0)
    at /team/project/src/threads/workerThread.cc:219
#2  0x00007ffff775e9d1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff6c07b5d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_7.html#SEC42 for more info.

Also, when you set a breakpoint you can specify ***commands*** that will run everytime you hit that breakpoint. See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html#SEC35

So, if you know how many lines are in your function you could set a command to list all source lines of the function:

```
(gdb) break myClass::EntityTypeStruct::readAttributes
Breakpoint 1 at 0x61ec3b: file /team/project/src/EntityTypeStruct.cc, line 38.
(gdb) commands 1
list 38,104
end
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but clearly the best answer.

Comment: How? It doesn't even answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

gdbtui can be useful to view the source during debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The 'frame' command shows the function name and the current line location and sets the current line for list to the current executable line.

```
set listsize 17
frame
list
```

lists the 8 lines surrounding the current line.