# View/Print function code from within GDB

Tags: view, printing, gdb

I am trying to develop a simple text based user interface which runs some gdb commands.
I want to user to be able to set and break/trace point at a certain area of the code and run some debug commands.

I want to user to enter the function which needs to be debugged. I then take this function name and print out the source code of the function, then ask the user to select which line of code at which to set the break/trace point. At the moment, using the disassemble command I can print out the memory addresses for the user, but i want to print the actual source code instead.

Can this be done in gdb?

Currently:

```
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x03800f70 <test_function+0>:  push   %ebp
   0x03800f71 <test_function+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x03800f73 <test_function+3>:  sub    $0x48,%esp
```

What I want:

```
void main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm getting this:

```
(gdb) list myFunction
941     directory/directory_etc/sourcefile.c: No such file or directory.
        in directory/directory_etc/sourcefile.c
```

then i tried specifying linenum:

```
(gdb) list directory/directory_etc/sourcefile.c:941
936     in directory/directory_etc/sourcefile.c
```

So the behaviour is similar to what you are describing, but "list filename:linenum" still isnt working

Thank you!

Comment: Current function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824251/gdb-list-source-of-current-function-without-typing-its-name

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
(gdb) list FUNCTION
```

See the online help of the `list` command for details:

```
(gdb) help list
List specified function or line.
With no argument, lists ten more lines after or around previous listing.
"list -" lists the ten lines before a previous ten-line listing.
One argument specifies a line, and ten lines are listed around that line.
Two arguments with comma between specify starting and ending lines to list.
Lines can be specified in these ways:
  LINENUM, to list around that line in current file,
  FILE:LINENUM, to list around that line in that file,
  FUNCTION, to list around beginning of that function,
  FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
  *ADDRESS, to list around the line containing that address.
With two args if one is empty it stands for ten lines away from the other arg.
```

For any non-toy projects, you'll probably hit a case like this:

```
$ gdb /bin/true
<...>
(gdb) start
<...>
(gdb) list printf
file: "/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h", line number: 104
file: "printf.c", line number: 29
```

Which lists the multiple definitions of a function in a code base. In the `printf()` case above, the non-overloaded pure C function has two definitions. One defined in `stdio2.h`. You can then use the `list FILE:LINENUM` form to specify which one you want to list:

```
(gdb) list printf.c:29
24  
25  /* Write formatted output to stdout from the format string FORMAT.  */
26  /* VARARGS1 */
27  int
28  __printf (const char *format, ...)
29  {
30    va_list arg;
31    int done;
32  
33    va_start (arg, format);
```

For the "sourcefile.c: No such file or directory" errors you're seeing, you need to tell GDB where to  look for the source code. See [GDB Manual: Source Path](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html). Obviously you'll need to actually have the source code for the function you want to list on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, when i run this command on a simple file (HelloWorld.exe) it works no problem. However, I am trying to use gdb to debug a large live system. The function I want to view is in one of many c files, which are compiled into a .elf file and when I run it on there I get: (gdb) list FUNCTION
941     in directory/directory_etc/code.c

Comment: @user2342775, I've amended my answer for the case when gdb's list command shows several definitions for a function name. Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: I've edited my original question to try to make it more readable, thank you!

Comment: Is there by any chance a way to ask `gdb` where the function is defined?

Comment: @x-yuri, yes! Try "(gdb) info line MY_FUNCTION".

I've written some notes here about using GDB to help navigate the code of the Linux kernel https://docs.google.com/document/d/1w1nPmCLpeRN3kEYglzHwozhWXY0ddT9oe6JCZocsPNE/edit#

To really use these features, you'll want to read "Chapter 9 Examining Source Files" of the GDB manual.

Answer (score 1):

**For gcc**:

Add a debugging option flag -g with the compilation of your source:

```
gcc -g test.c
```

To test, use:

```
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) list
```

For even more functionality, check out the man pages:

```
man gcc
man gdb
```